Masstransit Claim pattern - AzureStorage repository creation
I was reading the following documentation link regarding the Claim Pattern in MassTransit and I was wondering if I've to run that command
var client = new BlobServiceClient("<storage account connection string>");
_repository = client.CreateMessageDataRepository("message-data");

only one or I can leave it inside the configuration and it'll be skipped if it is already present.
My concern is regarding a potential configuration change (for example, a new DevOps environment) and the necessity to remember that command vs putting it in the codebase and having it running all the time.
Any suggestion around that?
Thanks

It uses CreateIfNotExists so it should be any problem to run it multiple times. It's expected that you'd just have this in your application and MassTransit will create the container if it doesn't already exist.
